# How to create an auto-select dropdown field with more than one value?

Tags: symfony, dropdown

I've created an auto-submit dropdown field and it works fine whenever only one value is given. Example below:

```
    <select name="stat" onchange="this.form.submit();">
      <option name="stat"
            {% if app.request.get('stat') == '1' %}
            selected="selected"
            {% endif %} value="1">Data
      </option>
      <option name="stat"
            {% if app.request.get('stat') == '2' %}
            selected="selected" {% endif %} value="2">Data2
      </option>
      <option name="stat"
            {% if app.request.get('stat') == '3' %}
            selected="selected"
            {% endif %} value="3">Data
      </option>
         </select>
```

but what I want to do is to create an option wherein **more than one value** is selected. Example below but it **doesn't work** for me.

```
   <option name="stat"
      {% if app.request.get('stat') == '1' or app.request.get('stat') == '2'
      or app.request.get('stat') == '3'
      %}
      selected="selected" {% endif %} value ="all"> All
  </option>
```

Repository:

```
   public function getStat($stat) {

        $em = $this->getEntityManager();
        $query = $em->createQuery(

                'SELECT partial a.{names},
                partial b.{stat,sender},
                partial c.{nametypeId, nametype}
                FROM MatrixNameBundle:file a
                WHERE b.stat LIKE :stat')

        ->setParameter('stat', $stat);
```

Please someone could help me with this!!!

Answer (score 0):

If you would look at the generated HTML code, you would probably see that multiple `<option>` element would have the `selected` attribute, given your code and one of the defined values. However, a HTML select input by default can only have one selected value. To allow multiple selection, you need to add the `multiple` attribute:

```
<select multiple>
...
</select>
```

Comment: when clicking my page, it doesn't display anything not until the user clicks/select from the dropdown. But I want that all files will display on the page and while the user can also select from the dropdown. How can I do it?